# Calling a VST plugin with VST.net in Unity3D. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, vst

I dont have any experience with [VST](https://www.steinberg.net/en/products/vst.html). Just started researching.

I need to call the member function VSTPluginMain from my VST dll to do some custom audio processing in my Unity 5 project. For a VST host, I added [VST.NET 1.0 CLR2 X64](https://vstnet.codeplex.com/) Release dlls in my project. I've read Unity supports only Common Language Runtime 2.

The documentation for VST.net is not working (a blank .chm file and the online version is incomplete). I wasn't able to find any useful samples in the VST.net project templates.
Also, does Unity support VST? (the Unity forums are silent about this matter)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The VST.NET site says _"VST.NET targets the **4.0** framework (runtime)"_.  Are you sure you have a CLR2 library?  Yes Unity is CLR2-only sadly.  Anyway here is a link you may find useful http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/vst-synths-effects-in-unity.9913/  Wishing you well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've downloaded the .chm right-click for the properties and find the "Unblock" button (for Windows).

There is a Host sample on the codeplex site that demonstrates how the host API calls work - but it is not a working VST host. Creating a VST host requires a lot of work and is not for the faint at heart.

It has been a while but I think there is no problem in compiling VST.NET for .NET 2.0 but it does require an older Visual Studio (2008 I believe). The compatibility of the Jacobi.Vst.Interop assembly determines the support for the .NET framework because it is the first assembly to load. So If you build the interop assembly to .NET 2.0 the other pure .NET assemblies will follow (Any CPU).

Hope it helps,
Marc (Author of VST.NET)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So creating a VST host with VST.net is a dead end basically, in my case ?

Comment: Depends on how much effort you wish to invest? If you just want to play some midi and have some sound effects I would think it is not the way to go. VST is for a plugable architecture, so unless you really need that, you're doing it wrong IMHO. There are plenty code examples for MIDI and DSP in C++ which is easily converted to C# (not sure what your language is)... My advise: start simple but modular. This allows you to change your hardcoded sound processing later on...